# Why is toString() an implicit override of java.lang.object?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, overriding

Today, I was writing a java class with a `toString()` method, and I noticed the `^` arrow Eclipse puts when you override a method in a superclass.  I did some clarification research after finding out that I was overriding `java.lang.object.toString` and found that every class has `java.lang.object` as their superclass (ref [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/java_lang_object.htm)).

Normally, when I see overriding, it has the annotation `@Override`.

My question is, why is my `toString()` method implicitly (without `@Override`) overriding the `toString()` method of the superclass `java.lang.object`?

Comment: Sorry, but the question is a little bit unclear. What do you mean when you say "implicitly"? If you want to make it more explicit by adding and `@Override` annotation, you're free to do so.

Comment: Implicitly.  Not using `@override`

Comment: But it's your own class. You can add it if you want to... The annotation is entirely optional and is only there to clarify your intention to the compiler, i.e. if you add the annotation but you're not actually overriding a method, you'll get a compiler warning/error.

Comment: If you would have taken a second to test this would every other superclass method in any given class you'd see the behavior is the same always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to use the `@Override` to override a method, it always override it (maybe at some point in history the annotation was needed, I don't know). If you write a method with the same signature of a super class method it will get override.

If you don't want a method to be override set it to private or final (if it's a public method)

Comment: The historical reason is the opposite actually: This annotation was introduced in JDK5 (and improved in JDK6). So it cannot be required as to not break compatibility with older code. All it does now is an opt-in extra check that the method does in fact override something. Prevents spelling mistakes or things like `equals(MyClass x)`  (which does not override equals in Object, even though many people assume it does).

Answer (score 1):

@override is an annotation. It actually doesn't translate to any byte code on compilation. It's more of an hint for the compiler and a clear visual cue for the dev to understand that it overrides it

Comment: That's true, but (1) incorrect use of an annotation can still abort the compile process, (2) a missing annotation might conceivable also abort the compile process (not being done to my knowledge at the moment) and (3) some annotations are retained in the class file (which is quite close to the "byte code")

Answer (score 1):

As others already pointed out, the `@Override` annotation is not required for overriding a method. The [Java API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/Override.html) describes the purpose very clearly. `@Override` tells the compiler that you want a method to override a class from a superclass. So to the compiler can warn you if you a typo in the method name or if the signature of the method does not match the signature of any method from a superclass.